Symfony - Form submit through sub-request by twig render(controller())
I am currently working on a Symfony 6.4 project.
On my main page, I have a list of entities. I want to propose a way to import/export those entities. For the imports, I have a form that is displayed inside a bootstrap modal.
The way I'd like to handle this is :

A page show.html.twig, that is a page showing all my entities as a table, and displaying a link/button. Controller would be EquipmentController::show(), that would be responsible only for displaying entities.
Another controller ExportImportController::import(), responsible of handling the form and displaying the bootstrap modal.

I managed to do something like that, the import mechanism works, but my main issue is : after submitting the form, if I refresh the page, the request is somehow "remembered" and the form is re-submitted. Therefore, my import is done once again, and I have duplicates.
You cant find my work so far below (the main parts, i removed the imports etc ...). The form is pretty basic : a FileType input field, and a 'save' button.
class EquipmentController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Show all Equipment entities.
     */
    #[Route('/equipment/show', name: 'route_equipment_show')]
    public function show(Request $request): Response
    {
        $vars = [];
        $vars['equipments'] = $this->equipmentRepository->findAll();

        return $this->render('Equipment/show.html.twig', $vars);
    }
}

class ExportImportController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/equipment/import', name: 'route_equipment_import', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function import(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(DeviceImportType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $vars['form'] = $form->createView();

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($form->has('save')) {
                /** @var ClickableInterface $buttonSave */
                $buttonSave = $form->get('save');
                if ($buttonSave->isClicked()) {
                    $this->importer->import($request);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('Equipment/import.html.twig', $vars);
    }
}

import.html.twig

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ form_label(form.file) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

show.html.twig

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\Equipment\\ExportImportController::import', {request: app.request})) }}

    < Simple rendering of a table here >

{% endblock %}

How can I somehow "clear" the sub-request in order to prevent re-submitting the form on page reload (F5) please ?
I'm open to any suggestions.
Thanks in advance !

I found a solution :
EquipmentController::show() :

$form = $this->createForm(DeviceImportType::class, null, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('route_equipment_show')
]);

